How to optimize parametric information-theoretic bounds?
I am faced with an information-theoretic upper bound, such as
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\alpha'}2^{I_\alpha(X;Y)},
\end{align}
where $I_\alpha(X;Y)$ is the Rényi mutual information with parameter $\alpha>1$ defined as
\begin{align*}
I_{\alpha}(X;Y)=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1} \log\left(\sum_y \left[\sum_x p(x)p(y|x)^{\alpha}\right]^{1/\alpha}\right),
\end{align*}
and $\alpha'$ is the Hölder conjugate of $\alpha$. I want to find the optimal $\alpha$ that minimizes this bound. However, differentiating with respect to $\alpha$ is not computationally tractable to find $\alpha$. Is there any way to handle such a minimization?

I can solve it numerically, but I want a closed-form solution.

Mathematica can easily do the differentiation by $\alpha$, however, solving for a minimum fails -- there doesn't seem to be a closed-form expression obtainable using known methods.
